# SharePoint Calendar Date & Time (Restrict or customize)

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-calendar

> Is there a way to restrict or customize SharePoint Calendar time presented in drop down?

For instance, my department uses SharePoint calendar to book appointments but we can't restrict or customize calendar to offer timings for the customers to pick `between 8:00 am - 4:00 pm only`. By default `start time shows 3pm and end time shows 4pm`.

Sincerely appreciate the help from the community regarding this issue.

Comment: I think you can develop a custom form with JQuery and use REST API to add/update to the calendar.

Comment: I bet it is possible to do this using the Validation section of the list to check if the time for the [Start time] and [end time] are between those hours. I just haven't figured out the formula yet.

Answer (score 0):

Go into calendar settings and select Validation and put in the following code to validate the time between the [Start Time] and [End Time].

Example where the **start time** is >= 8am and the **end time** is <= 4pm.

```
=AND(TIME(HOUR([Start Time]),Minute([Start Time]),Second([Start Time]))>=TIME(8,0,0),TIME(HOUR([End Time]),Minute([End Time]),Second([End Time]))<=TIME(16,0,0))
```

Then add the following message in the validation user message box: **Please select time between 8:00 AM and 4:00 PM. All Day Events are not allowed.**

To expand upon the numbered section of the code we have (8,0,0) standing for (8:00 AM) in (hours, minutes, sections) using the 24 hour clock numbering system. Feel free to adjust the time as needed. I threw in the note about all day events not allowed because it removes time and causes the validation to become false when no time is present in the start/end fields.

I found the answer on this forum and modified the code. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/32e9e3c4-2d60-41e2-87f6-f9ae14b6977c/how-to-create-a-validation-rule-for-a-specific-time-interval?forum=sharepointadminprevious